# Determine whether series is convergent or divergent $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I still haven't gotten the hang of how to solve these problems, but when I first saw this one I thought partial fraction or limit.  So I went with taking the limit but the solution manual shows them using the integral test.

Was I wrong to just take the limit?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+4}$$

Next:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+4}=0$$

So converges by the test for divergence?

Comment: The test for divergence can only show you that a series diverges if the limit is *not* zero. If the limit of the size of the terms *is* zero, then the divergence test is inconclusive. That's why they call it the divergence test.

Comment: When $\displaystyle{\large n \gg 2, {1 \over n^{2} + 4} \sim {1 \over n^{2}}}$ which is the Basel Problem. It converges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We only have the following statement to be true:
$$\text{If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$.}$$ The converse of the above statement is not true, i.e.,
$$\text{if $a_n \to 0$, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges is an incorrect statement.}$$

For instance, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1n$ diverges, even though $\dfrac1n \to 0$.

To prove your statement, note that $\dfrac1{n^2+4} < \dfrac1{n^2}$ and make use of the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^2}$ converges to conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2+4}$ converges.

Comment: Awesome! I see exactly what you mean, I assumed too much was true when in fact its only true that the sequence approaches 0, not the series?

Answer (score 5):

Just expounding on $\frac{1}{n^2 + 4} < \frac{1}{n^2}$ in the above answer.

This holds using the Comparison Test which states that if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are such that $0 \le a_n \le b_n$, if $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: So I could use this test or the integral test then?

Comment: To use the Integral Test, $f(x)$ which in this case would be $\frac{1}{x^2 +4}$ has to be positive ($f(x) \ge 0$), non-increasing on $(N, \infty \rbrace$. Then you'd find the limit of the integral of $f(x)$. If the limit $\to$ a constant then $\sum a_n$ converges. So it'd work for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another way,
that needs fewer theorems:

$n^2+4
> n(n-1)$
so
$\frac1{n^2+4}
< \frac1{n(n-1)}
= \frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n}
$.

Therefore,
for any $m > 0$
$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac1{n^2+4}
< \sum_{n=2}^m (\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n})
= 1-\frac1{m}
< 1
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac1{n^2+4}$
converges as $m \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + 4}
&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1 + 2\ic}\pars{n + 1 - 2\ic}}
=
{\Psi\pars{1 + 2\ic} - \Psi\pars{1 - 2\ic} \over \pars{1 + 2\ic} - \pars{1 - 2\ic}}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\Psi\pars{1 + 2\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 4} + {1 \over 2}\,\pi\coth\pars{2\pi}}
\end{align}
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + 4}}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large{1 \over 4}\bracks{\pi\coth\pars{2\pi} - {1 \over 2}}}
\approx 0.6604
$$